# Import Enum File Imcompability with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, enums

I am having issues running a Python file that uses "import enum", giving me this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "lowest_common_ancestor.py", line 4, in <module>
    from test_framework import generic_test, test_utils

File "/Users/linh/Documents/EPIJudge/epi_judge_python/test_framework/generic_test.py", line 6, in <module>
    from test_framework.generic_test_handler import GenericTestHandler

File "/Users/linh/Documents/EPIJudge/epi_judge_python/test_framework/generic_test_handler.py", line 5, in <module>
    from test_framework.binary_tree_utils import assert_equal_binary_trees, is_object_tree_type

File "/Users/linh/Documents/EPIJudge/epi_judge_python/test_framework/binary_tree_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    from test_framework.test_failure import TestFailure, PropertyName

File "/Users/linh/Documents/EPIJudge/epi_judge_python/test_framework/test_failure.py", line 2, in <module>    
from enum import Enum, auto

ImportError: cannot import name 'auto'
```

I know I have Python 2.7 and "import Enum" exists only with Python 3, but I am having troubles going about how to create two different environments where I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3. How would one go about doing this on Mac Unix terminal, which I also am not very familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` didn't show up until Python 3.6, and is not in the `enum34` backport.  If you want 2/3 compatible code you'll need to use [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/)<sup>1</sup>.

I do not have any experience with the Mac Unix terminal.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 1):

Or implement it your self like this:

```
# Implement the auto feature that becomes available in 3.6
autoinc = 0
def auto():
    global autoinc
    autoval = autoinc
    autoinc += 1
    return autoval

class AppState(Enum):
    SPLASH = auto()
    STATUS = auto()
    QRCODE = auto()
    FIREWORKS = auto()
    MESSAGES = auto()
```

Comment: every time you use mutable global state, a baby computer dies.